# looking for an inverted heap in python

Tags: python, overloading, heap

I'd like to comb off the n largest extremes from a timeseries.
heapq works perfectly for the nlargest

```
def nlargest(series, n):
    count = 0
    heap = []
    for e in series:
        if count < n:
            count+=1
            hp.heappush(heap, e)
        else:
            # keeps heap size fixed 
            hp.heappushpop(heap,e)  
    ''' note: heap[0] is smallest '''
    return heap
```

but what about the n smallest?  Note that i want a subset of the original series, so heapify and reversing the order won't work.  What I'd like is essentially to overload the comparison operator from gt to lt.  Not so familiar with overloading in python.

A less attractive option would (assuming numerical values) would be to negate the item before inserting and then negate the entire return heap (return a list or re-heap the negated list) but this seems kludgy and it no longer works for non-numericals that do have gt and lt.  Any elegant solutions?

Comment: do you know how to manually construct a heap (Its one of the easier data structs) ... it wouldnt be hard to just manually implement this

Comment: That sounds like fun.  I guess i was thinking of something like the c++ qsort: void qsort(void *base, size_t count, size_t size, int (*comp)(const void *e1, const void *e2)) where you can pass in your own compare function (*comp).  Maybe my heapq will do that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily 'create' an inverted heap by multiplying the priorities of your items by -1.

So your `nsmallest` simply needs to be told how to 'invert' the priorities, decorating each value as needed:

```
def nsmallest(series, n, invert=lambda x: -1 * x):
    count = 0
    heap = []
    for e in series:
        if count < n:
            count += 1
            hp.heappush(heap, (invert(e), e))
        else:
            # keeps heap size fixed
            hp.heappushpop(heap, (invert(e), e))  
    # note: heap[0][1] is largest, remove inverted priorities
    return [h[1] for h in heap]
```

Note that we use a `(invertedpriority, value)` tuple to keep the heap inverted.

For non-numericals, you'd have to simply provide a inversion function that turns the priorities upside down, it only needs to be a simple key, not something that is readable or anything:

```
alphanumeric_invert = lambda x: [(ord(c) * -1) for c in x]
```

However, rather than write your own, you want to use the [`heapq.nsmallest()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nsmallest), which uses an optimised max-heap implementation (there is an internal `_heappop_max()` function it uses), which also adds a tie-breaker counting value to keep the sort stable. And there is a matching [`heapq.nlargest()` function](https://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest).

Comment: I have to disagree about triple-quoted strings: Guido has suggested using it this way [(link)](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248).  I prefer to use `"""`, though, so that I can use `'''` to comment out groups of functions containing `"""`.

Comment: @DSM: Interesting; didn't know they end up being dropped from the bytecode! Removed the remark (the answer I linked was in the context of someone expecting them to ignore indentation like a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`heapq.nsmallest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html) from the Python standard library:

> ```
> heapq.nsmallest(n, iterable[, key])
> ```
>
> Return a list with the `n` smallest elements from the dataset defined by `iterable`. Equivalent to: `sorted(iterable, key=key)[:n]`