# heapq module python

Tags: python, list, priority-queue

I'm using the `heapq` module to determine the smallest item in a list.

I have this below code, but the `heapq.heapify()` return value is None.

How do I get the result in a new list?

```
>>> a=heapq.heapify(lista)
>>> a
>>> lista=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a=heapq.heapify(lista)
>>> print(a)
None
```

Answer (score 10):

`heapq.heapify` doesn't return anything, it heapifies the list in place; it's far more efficient to do it that way:

```
>>> import heapq
>>> lista = [44, 42, 3, 89, 10]
>>> heapq.heapify(lista)
>>> lista
[3, 10, 44, 89, 42]
```

If you need a *new* list, create a copy first:

```
>>> lista = [44, 42, 3, 89, 10]
>>> newlist = lista[:]
>>> heapq.heapify(newlist)
>>> lista
[44, 42, 3, 89, 10]
>>> newlist
[3, 10, 44, 89, 42]
```

That defeats the purpose somewhat, of course, as copying the list has a (linear) cost too.

If all you need is the smallest item in a list, the [`min()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#min) will be *just as fast* when locating just the one smallest element (both `heapify()` and `min()` scan the input list once, so O(n) cost):

```
>>> min(lista)
3
```

If you need more than one smallest value, by all means use a `heapq`, especially if you add items later on. If you cannot alter the original list, need several smallest items, see [looking for an inverted heap in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356564/looking-for-an-inverted-heap-in-python/12356586#12356586) for an efficient `nsmallest` implementation that creates a new heap from an input heap with *only* a fixed number of smallest values.

Comment: he may not be familiar with typical heap implementation and traversal

Answer (score 0):

You have to use heapq.nsmallest(k,arr) function.  //k here is 1 as you want one minimum value.

```
>>> a=heapq.heapify(lista)
>>> a
>>> lista=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a=heapq.nsmallest(1,lista)
>>> print(a)
1
```